# clang linking error : unable to find library -lclang_rt.builtins-arm.a

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I am trying to build ChibiOS using clang , but currently i am stuck at below linking error.
Linking build/ch.elf
clang-7: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostartfiles' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/home/quest/clang_build/clang_all/build/bin/ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lclang_rt.builtins-arm.a
clang-7: error: ld.lld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
../../../os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/LLVM/mk/rules.mk:208: recipe for target 'build/ch.elf' failed
make: *** [build/ch.elf] Error 1

I did downloaded the lib and provided the path in makefile but still its not picked up (ldd might be looking at a specific path for this).
Any help on this ?

Comment: I think the linker is not able to find the specified library. give in the library path using `-L` flag and then write the name of the static library you want to link too.

Comment: Already i tried the following -L/<path>/libclang_rt.builtins-arm.a in Makefile but ldd linker in not picking it. I guess linker is looking for a specified path which i am not able to find out , may be i am wrong.

Comment: you need to type the "folder path" with `-L`. e,g `-L<path_to_clang_rt> -lclang_rt.builtins-arm` .  I think this should work

Comment: I tried it but same error , I have added - @$(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -L/home/clang_build/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/softfp/ -L/home/Downloads/ -lclang_rt.builtins-arm $(LIBS) -o $@

Comment: With above change i still get following error /home/clang_build/llvm_clang_lld/build/bin/ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lclang_rt.builtins-arm.a
clang-7: error: ld.lld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) , also the libs from -L/home/clang_build/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/softfp/ is taken (i tried copying the lib in this path too with our success).

Comment: what is the name of your library? is it called "libclang_rt.builtins-arm.a"?

Comment: Yes its libclang_rt.builtins-arm.a

Comment: What's in your `$(LIBS)`?

Comment: $(LIBS) is empty

Comment: This might be a linker bug. You can try replacing llvm linker with gcc linker.

Comment: Currently I am trying it with arm-none-eabi-gcc linker and not observed this linking issue. Once i complete it , i will update it here. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: I could compile ChibiOS using clang/llvm compiler and did linking using arm-none-eabi linker.

Comment: that's great! Where was the problem?